# Python/pygame: Usage of surfarray.pixels3d()

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

Using the following code:

```
import pygame
n = pygame.Surface((80,80))
m = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(n)

m[1][1][1] = 255
del m

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((80,80))
screen.blit(n, (0,0))
```

Gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pygame.error: Surfaces must not be locked during blit
```

Didn't I just delete the reference?

Comment: Any luck if you try http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html instead?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a case where the pygame documentation is just unclear. It SAYS the referenced surface will be locked for the lifetime of the array, but deleting the array won't actually unlock the surface that it references. Use `n.unlock()` to unlock the surface before blitting.

Comment: To be clear the procedure is  `del m` then `n.unlock`. Both steps are necessary